# Another exercise from Fleming's Functions of Several Variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I'm using Flemming's book Function of Several Variables.

In it, the author defines Manifolds like this:
Let $1\le r\lt n,\ q\ge1$. A nonempty set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a manifold of dimension $r$ and class $C^{(q)}$ if $M$ has the property that for every point $\mathbf{x_0} \in M$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\mathbf{x_0}$ and a $\mathbf{\Phi}=(\Phi^1,\dots,\Phi^{n-r})$ of class $C^{(q)}$ on $U$, such that $D\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})$ has rank $n-r$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in U$ and

$M \cap U= \{\mathbf{x}\in U :\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})=0 \}$.

The exercise is the following:
Let $\Psi^l(\mathbf{x})=g^l(\mathbf{x}) \Phi ^l(\mathbf{x})$, where $g^l(\mathbf{x})\neq 0$ and is of class C^1, for $l=1,\dots, n-r$. We must show that $D\mathbf{\Psi}(\mathbf{x})$ has rank $n-r$ for every $\mathbf{x}\in U$.

We know that the rows of $D\mathbf{\Psi}(\mathbf{x})$, $d\Psi^l(\mathbf{x})=dg^l(\mathbf{x})\cdot\Phi^l(\mathbf{x})+g^l(\mathbf{x})\cdot d\Phi^l(\mathbf{x})$. And by this definition of manifold, $d\Phi^l(\mathbf{x})$ are linearly independent. So, how do I prove that $d\Psi^l(\mathbf{x})$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that $\Phi^l(\mathbf{x})=0$, for every $\mathbf{x} \in U$.

Hence, $\{d\Psi^l(\mathbf{x})=g^l(\mathbf{x})\cdot d\Phi^l(\mathbf{x}):l=1,\dots,n-r\}$ is a set of linear independent vectors, since linear transformations preserve linear independence.